# Facebook Like button inside a page in an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, iframe

I'm trying to use fb "like" button inside a window that I created (aspx), this window loads in an iframe (has nothing to do with fb iframe), when I press the like button, the dialog that opens doesn't has the details that I put in the meta  tags, though, if I enter the page - not from iframe, when I press the "like" button, everything loads good, when I look at the iframe source, I can see the meta tags, but from some reason, it's not working inside the iframe, any1 know the answer?

this is page that goes inside the iframe (code is partial):

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="My Article Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:8081/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost:8081/photos/LogoHeaderNew.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My article description" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
              <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
        <div id="Div_FaceBook" style="display:inline-block;float:left;margin-top:10px;margin-right:15px;margin-top:8px;width:auto;">                 
             <fb:like href="http://localhost:8081" show_faces="false" share="false" width="450" font="" data-layout="button_count">
             </fb:like>
         </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because Facebook's servers can't see the page at `http://localhost:8081`.

For you to be able to like a URL, that URL must be visible on the open web so Facebook can do an HTTP GET on that URL and read the metatags inside.

Answer (score 0):

Since the open graph url you are pointing is on localhost Facebook is not able to crawl into the page.